# Autenticar en firebase mi propio usuario y contraseña

Tags: angularjs, ionic, firebase

Tratando de usar **firebase** para poder utilizar todo lo correspondiente a la sincronización y demás bondades de la plataforma, me he encontrado con un inconveniente que no logro resolver.

Cómo poder crear un inicio de sesión pero utilizando usuarios y contraseñas creados por mí, por ejemplo:

```
Usuario: jguzman
Contraseña: 123456
```

y NO solamente usando el inicio de sesión por medio de redes sociales o correo electrónico.

Comment: Puedes ser más específico con tu pregunta? Explícalo mejor porque sino te la marcaran en espera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedro, en el caso de Firebase las opciones para autenticar son a traves de proveedores como son Google, Facebook, Twitter, Github, además de email.

[image]

El caso que comentas, administrar y crear inicios de sesión únicamente con usuario y contraseña no es posible, al menos tiene que realizarse mediante un email, esto se tiene en Firebase para tener la facilidad de integrarse con un sistema de cuentas de email.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion

Comment: Excelente Pedro, saludos!.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias hacerlo usando el `usuario` y añadiendole un dominio de correo cualquiera, pero perderias la forma de recuperar la contraseña

ej: *nombredeusuario@myapp.com* -> el usuario ingresa `nombredeusuario` y tu le colocas el `@myapp.com`

Firebase necesita un correo para poder crear el sistema de registro y poder recuperar la contraseña de un usuario

Comment: No sabia eso, pero gracias por la información.